# Fail to apply mapping on an RDD on multipe spark nodes through Elasticsearch-hadoop library

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, apache-spark, rdd, elasticsearch-hadoop

```
import org.elasticsearch.spark._
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.serializer._;
import com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo;
import org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.EsSpark 

sc.stop()

val conf = new SparkConf()
conf.set("es.index.auto.create","true")
conf.set("spark.serializer", classOf[KryoSerializer].getName)

conf.set("es.nodes","localhost")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

val getAllQuery = "{\"query\":{\"match_all\":{}}}"
val esRDDAll = sc.esRDD("test-index/typeA", getAllQuery)

//WORKS
esRDDAll.count

//WORKS
EsSpark.saveToEs(esRDDAll, "output-index/typeB")

val esRDDMap = esRDDAll.map(r => r)

//FAILS
esRDDMap.count

//FAILS
EsSpark.saveToEs(esRDDMap, "output-index/typeB")
```

The error I am getting is:

```
WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 41, localhost): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: $line594.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream$$anon$1.resolveClass(JavaSerializer.scala:68)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1613)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1518)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1774)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:76)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:115)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:61)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

#### Note

This only occurs when I am using master slave mode in Spark. On a single node it works fine.

Comment: Did you try the newer dataframe API in sql sub-package? using sc.esDF

Comment: Does Dataframe support mapping @PranavShukla?

Comment: Are you sure all classes are properly available to all workers?

Comment: So you are using spark-shell? could you paste the command used to start spark-shell?

Comment: This is in spark shell that is right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have encountered similar issues, and I hope those two links might help :

- [SPARK-4170](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-4170)
- [SPARK-2175](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2175)